# Arris BGW210-700, IP passthrough, and subnets

Tags: networking, router, nat, gateway, time-capsule

I've got an Arris BGW210-700 residential gateway for an AT&T fiber connection to my house. Under **Firewall** > **IP Passthrough**, I have **Allocation Mode** set to **Default Server** and **Default Server Internal Address** set to the IP address of my own router (an Apple Time Capsule).

This set-up works, but I'd prefer the BGW210-700 to be in pure Passthrough mode, i.e., assign the publicly routable IP address to the WAN port of my Time Capsule.  Currently, there's a double NAT happening because I'd prefer to configure my WiFi devices from the Time Capsule, so it manages the 192.168.2.x subnet for WiFi.

I can set **Allocation Mode** to **Passthrough** and **Passthrough Fixed MAC Address** to that of my Time Capsule.

My question is: if I do this and the publicly routable IP address is "passed through," then how can I access the BGW210-700 itself?  (Currently, I access it via `http://192.168.1.254`.)  I tried something like this once and the BGW210-700 became inaccessible. (I had to reset it to factory defaults to recover.)

The BGW210-700 has 4 ethernet ports on the back: one goes to the Time Capsule.  Ideally, I want the other 3 ports to be on the 192.168.1.x subnet and the Time Capsule to serve the 192.168.2.x subnet *without* double NAT'ing (which IP Passthrough *should* give me).  The devices on the two different subnets never need to talk to each other (with the exception of me being able to access the BGW210-700 itself via WiFi > Time Capsule).

Pictorially:

```
Fiber -> ONT -> BGW210-700
                * LAN: 192.168.1.254
                |
                +-> Other misc devices (via ethernet cables)
                |   * LAN: 192.168.1.x
                |   |
                |   +-> VOIP box
                |   +-> Security system box
                |   +-> ...
                |
                +-> Time Capsule
                    * LAN: 192.168.2.1
                    |
                    +-> True home network (via WiFi)
                        * LAN: 192.168.2.x
                        |
                        +-> Desktop computer
                        +-> Laptop computer
                        +-> ...
```

How can I do what I want?

Answer (score -1):

1. Setting Up Passthrough:

   - On the BGW210-700, navigate to Firewall > IP Passthrough.
   - Change Allocation Mode to Passthrough.
   - Enter the Passthrough Fixed MAC Address of your Time Capsule's WAN port (usually found on a sticker on the device itself).
   - Save the changes.
2. Accessing the BGW210-700 After Passthrough.
   Since the BGW210-000 won't have a public IP anymore, you won't be able to access it from the internet. But you can still access it from your local network through your Time Capsule:

   - Connect a device (laptop, phone, etc.) to your Time Capsule's WiFi network.
   - Open a web browser on the connected device.
   - In the address bar, enter the default LAN IP of the BGW210-700, which is usually http://192.168.1.254.
3. Configuring Subnets:
   On the BGW210-700 (before enabling passthrough):
   Although not strictly necessary for passthrough, it's recommended to configure the BGW210-700's LAN subnet to a different range than the one you plan to use for your Time Capsule (e.g., change it to 192.168.10.0/24). This helps avoid potential IP conflicts later.
4. On your Time Capsule:

   - Once in passthrough mode, log in to your Time Capsule's settings.
   - Look for options related to LAN or Network.
   - Set the Time Capsule's LAN IP address to something within the desired subnet (e.g., 192.168.2.1).
   - Configure the DHCP server settings on your Time Capsule to distribute IP addresses within the same subnet (e.g., 192.168.2.x range).
   - Save the changes.
5. Final Touches:

   - After configuring both devices, restart them for the changes to take effect.
   - Your other devices connected via ethernet to the BGW210-700 (VOIP, Security system) will now be on the 192.168.1.x subnet assigned by the BGW200 (assuming you didn't change it).
   - Devices connected to your Time Capsule's WiFi will be on the 192.168.2.x subnet managed by the Time Capsule.

Important Note:
Double-check that your Time Capsule supports functioning as a primary router with DHCP server capabilities. Some models might only be designed for extending existing networks.